# Rails 6 app not executing JS code in javascript/packs/application.js file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a custom JS code in my packs/application.js file.

But I'm not sure why the code is not recognized.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
console.log(container);
var slider = document.getElementById('slider');
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slide').length;
var buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('btn');

var currentPosition = 0;
var currentMargin = 0;
var slidesPerPage = 0;
var slidesCount = slides - slidesPerPage;
var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
var prevKeyActive = false;
var nextKeyActive = true;

window.addEventListener('resize', checkWidth);

function checkWidth() {
  containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
  setParams(containerWidth);
}

function setParams(w) {
  if (w < 551) {
    slidesPerPage = 1;
  } else {
    if (w < 901) {
      slidesPerPage = 2;
    } else {
      if (w < 1101) {
        slidesPerPage = 3;
      } else {
        slidesPerPage = 4;
      }
    }
  }
  slidesCount = slides - slidesPerPage;
  if (currentPosition > slidesCount) {
    currentPosition -= slidesPerPage;
  }
  currentMargin = -currentPosition * (100 / slidesPerPage);
  slider.style.marginLeft = currentMargin + '%';
  if (currentPosition > 0) {
    buttons[0].classList.remove('inactive');
  }
  if (currentPosition < slidesCount) {
    buttons[1].classList.remove('inactive');
  }
  if (currentPosition >= slidesCount) {
    buttons[1].classList.add('inactive');
  }
}

setParams();

function slideRight() {
  if (currentPosition != 0) {
    slider.style.marginLeft = currentMargin + 100 / slidesPerPage + '%';
    currentMargin += 100 / slidesPerPage;
    currentPosition--;
  }
  if (currentPosition === 0) {
    buttons[0].classList.add('inactive');
  }
  if (currentPosition < slidesCount) {
    buttons[1].classList.remove('inactive');
  }
}

function slideLeft() {
  if (currentPosition != slidesCount) {
    slider.style.marginLeft = currentMargin - 100 / slidesPerPage + '%';
    currentMargin -= 100 / slidesPerPage;
    currentPosition++;
  }
  if (currentPosition == slidesCount) {
    buttons[1].classList.add('inactive');
  }
  if (currentPosition > 0) {
    buttons[0].classList.remove('inactive');
  }
}

// MODAL
var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
var btn = document.getElementById('myBtn');
var span = document.getElementsByClassName('close')[0];

btn.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = 'block';
};
span.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = 'none';
};
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = 'none';
  }
};

// SCROLL TO VIEW
const navBtn = document.querySelector('.nav-btn');
const heroBtn = document.querySelector('.hero-btn');
var signEl = document.querySelector('.sign-form');

navBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  signEl.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'start',
    inline: 'nearest',
  });
});
heroBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  signEl.scrollIntoView({
    behavior: 'smooth',
    block: 'start',
    inline: 'nearest',
  });
});
```

It just shows the following error:

```
null
application.js:27 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:27)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
./app/javascript/packs/application.js @ application.js:27
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:19
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
(anonymous) @ bootstrap:83
```

Line 27 is - `var containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;`

The application.js file is loaded in application.html.haml like so -
`= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload'`

The question is why is it not working?

Comment: Other code works?

Comment: Does your `console.log(container)` returns the Dom element ? If you are using bootstrap shouldn't it rather be a class than an ID ?

Comment: I believe the code got executed before the document loaded. You need to properly call it inside document ready or turbolinks load event

Comment: Thanks, @CR7 for your comment, this is the only JS code in the project.

Comment: Thanks, @Maxence for your comment. It doesn't return a Dom element, that's the first line 'null' in the error log above. Also, I am not using Twitter bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks, @Vibol for your comment, I've moved the code into a block of turbolinks:load like so - https://gist.github.com/mayordwells/753b6bd67e2af138b645efdeb9ccd6d2

The code now executes, the container Dom element is now logged in the console. Except for the functions in it: `slideRight() and slideLeft()`

The functions are called in the HTML template on click like so: `:onclick => "slideRight()"`

This is the error in the console:  `Uncaught ReferenceError: slideLeft is not defined
    at HTMLSpanElement.onclick ((index):300)
onclick @ (index):300`

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: @mayorsanmayor you can learn from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61871253/1600046