# Rails 7 esbuild - how to manage global javascript functions?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, esbuild

My goal is to create global functions that I can use throughout my application. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61871253/5095764) but couldn't really apply it. The most basic gist of what I am wanting to do is:

```
# app/javascript/application.js
  // define global function, but don't run it
  function removeFlash(){
    // do stuff
  }

# app/views/.../update.js.slim
|
  // do stuff
  // use the global function after other code is ran
  removeFlash()
```

I have a rails 7 esbuild created by doing `rails new testapp -j esbuild -d postgresql --css bootstrap`

I then added a few modules such as `jquery` and `flatpickr` via `yarn install`. My `application.js` file looks like:

```
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "./controllers"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
import './vendors/jquery'
import {} from 'jquery-ujs'
import flatpickr from "flatpickr"

$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log('hooray')
})
```

Within the application.js file I want to define a number of global functions so I can call them whenever needed throughout other files rather than repeating the same code over and over.

```
// Entry point for the build script in your package.json
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails"
import "./controllers"
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"
import './vendors/jquery'
import {} from 'jquery-ujs'
import flatpickr from "flatpickr"

function addFlash(msg){
  // do stuff
}

function removeFlash(){
  // do stuff
}

function performTask(){
  // do stuff
}
```

Since my forms are all remote and happen via js, I have multiple files that will need to run that those functions, such as:

```
# app/views/objects/create.js.slim
- if @obj.errors.any?
  ...
- else
  |
    $("#obj-list").append("#{escape_javascript(render 'obj_row', obj: @obj)}");
    $(".close-modal").click();
    addFlash("Object successfully created.");
    removeFlash();
```

And this would be duplicated for the update as well as other records.

Apart from just adding a `javascript:` tag to the bottom of the `app/views/layouts/application.html.slim` file and declaring all the functions there, I don't understand what the best practice is for handling the above situations.

```
# app/views/layouts/application.html.slim
doctype html
html
  head
    title TestApp
    ...
  body
    = yield

javascript:
  function addFlash(msg){
    // do stuff
  }
  ...
```

What is the best way or standard practice to create and use global functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better alternative to the `javascript:` tag in the views would be to put the function in the window object, like this:

```js
// app/javascript/application.js
  window.removeFlash = function() {
    // ...
  }
```

Then everywhere you use it, you have to call it as `window.removeFlash()`.

Comment: This works, but surely there must be a better way.  You should be able to declare javascript inside of your application.js and it should be accessible throughout the project.  Why is it that we have to assign this to the `window` in order to access it?